# Does ML-KIT includes vision camera text recognition API?

Tags: android, google-mlkit, vision-api

I want to turn on the camera and extract the text.
As it was here https://developers.google.com/vision
On the deprecated page of vision API it says that vision API been included in ML-KIT but I have found only image to text recognition. How to use camera text recognition not image text?

Comment: Did you not see: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition

Comment: @MorrisonChang it says "Recognize text in images with ML Kit on Android" the keyword in IMAGES. I need while camera is ON

Comment: If you check the [Android setup](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android) you'll see these (live) [camera performance tips](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android#performance-tips). You can also check the sample app: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart and see if it meets your requirements.